# What is the definition of algorithm and recursive theory in logic?

Tags: logic, algorithms

I am taking an introductory logic class in my graduate school, and I found terms such as "theory $T$ is recursive" and "there exists an algorithm that decides whether $\phi\in T$."

I tried to search this online, but it was hard to find the definitions of them in the context of logic. Could you provide me definitions for them and few examples please? (I found the definition of a theory being recursive in Marker's Model theory, but it uses "algorithm" to describe the definition)

Comment: Related: [Church-Turing thesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Church%E2%80%93Turing_thesis)

Comment: We can treat propositions as strings. An algorithm to decide whether $\phi \in T$ is a Turing machine which, given any $\phi$, will always halt and output whether $\phi \in T$. Saying $T$ is recursive means there is such an algorithm.